# how to avoid error when search cannot find value. Without setting object as range (value is Variant)

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a test to try search list'B' for values based on list'A'and displaying the results in list 'C'. I can use `On Error GoTo line` to skip out any items in the list that are not present but where the last one is not present it will still error. (this is a test for a far more complex Sub). Is there a better way of doing this as `If Not "Object" Is Nothing` only works when the object is a range?

Lists below:

```
A   B   C
1   1   1
2   2   2
3       
4   4   4
5   5   5
6   6   6
7
```

Code:

```
Sub test2()

    Dim startno As Integer
    Dim endno As Integer
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim y As Variant
    endno = 1000
    For startno = 1 To endno
        If IsEmpty(Range("1:1").Find(What:="A").Offset(startno, 0).Value) = False Then
            x = Sheets(1).Range("1:1").Find(What:="A").Offset(startno, 0).Value
            Sheets(1).Range("1:1").Find(What:="C").Offset(startno, 0).Value = Sheets(1).Range("B:B").Find(x).Value
            On Error GoTo line
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
line:
    Next startno
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("1:1").Find(What:="A")` returns a `Range`.  Test ***that*** for `Nothing` instead of immediately attempting to apply an `.Offset` to it.

Comment: ^ that. And then *indent your code* so that it's easier to tell where an `If` or `For` block starts and ends =)

Comment: ^ and ^^ and you should also note that, in your `IsEmpty`, you are checking something on the ActiveSheet but in the rest of your code you are working with `Sheets(1)`.  This doesn't seem consistent, and will undoubtedly lead you into all sorts of future problems.

Comment: Cheers guys. Makes way more sense.

p.s. do usually indent and name all ranges by workbooks and sheets. Was just a rough test.